# Fast writes into a persistent queue

Tags: java, mysql, performance, distributed, hdfs

I'm trying to change my current application to scale.

It can currently handle at most a few million events per hour but the volume is expected to grow 10 to 100 times fold as I switch to a SaaS model, so it is important to be able to execute the processing in a distributed fashion.

The app is a web application receiving at peek currently 1.2 million events/hour. It is using 2 Tomcat servers, each listening on 500 threads and a workManager to queue the events and will then spawn a couple of hundred worker threads to postprocess the events.

What I'm trying to do is decoupling the writing from processing and move the processing to a distributed environment.

1. Fast write to the disk the events.

   Here the solution can be as simple as writing to a LinkedBlockingQueue and dump batches of hundred, thousand of entries to a file or use a good library that does this already or tune the database to support this type of queueing in a reasonable fashion.

   Failing to capture the last events if the system becomes unavailable is not paramount, the focus is performance when the server is working.
2. Move the event processing to a distributed system.

   I need to move the data to a distributed system (e.g. HDFS). What other options are there?

   The processing is of medium complexity (e.g. some of the complexity is in a self-join generating a frequent itemset and further filtering down this set, other parts involve aggregating data across multiple hierarchies). I currently use a database (MySql & DB2) and thinking about Hadoop. Any other options?
3. Store the results in a readonly fast read system.

I am currently using SOLR, any better options?

I know the question spawns multiple topics, any input is appreciated. Let me know if there's a better tag I could use.

Thanks!

Sebi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best system today, capable of both insertions and queries - indeed is RDBMS. But it is not scalable. NoSQL systems are not scalable because they built better, but because they gave up something.. 
 Let see what can be built from them.
Both HBase a Cassandra are built specially to translate random events insertion to sequential disk IO. In other words - they are write optimized system and you can consider them as perfect distribtuted database index. So you can get to any insertion rate you need by adding more nodes

Regarding joins and aggregations is a problematic point there. 
If you will succeed to design your key in the way that data to be aggregated is collocated - data can be pulled and aggregated efficiently. 
Joins is also problematic but there is an option to write data already prejoined. You should do it in application level. 
For more complex processing you will need to resort to MapReduce but it probabbly will affect insertion rates. 
DataStax's Brisk sounds like good for your case since it has Cassandra preintegrated with the MapReduce with the capability to run MapReduce right over Cassandra Data. It also has capability to reduce MapReduce affect on the OLTP part of the story.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of your problems sound like they have JMS as the solution.  It's a queue, it's supposed to be fast, it's reliable (across machine failures), and it's persistent.

ActiveMQ, for example, can be configured to force a client to wait until the data has been committed to disc on more than one machine, by setting it up as a "network of brokers".  See http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

It also allows you to flag messages as persistent, such that the brokers can survive restarts.  I strongly recommend the ActiveMQ suggestion of http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html , as the older versions have serious issues.

This helps with the distribution of events, but doesn't help at all with the processing, nor the actual eventual storage of the data.  How many clients are going to need access to how much of the data, and how long after it has been produced?  You can use "topics" in JMS to distribute messages to all clients, and concepts like "last image topics" to store some state on the broker, so your clients can restart.  http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html explains these.

However, despite all that, it sounds like you're going to end up with Hadoop to process the information anyway, so may as well use anything built into their stack. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use memory mapped files as a persisted queue.

This library supports persisted event driven messages into the millions per second (not per hour) with sub-microsecond latencies between processes.  Its also pretty simple (too low level for most usages, but you can use it as a start)

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your suggestion. This looks interesting.
I could see using this to temporarily persists requests from all the web server threads and at the other side have N processes quickly moving the data in a batch fashion(every second or so) to my N machines in the distributed environment that will process the load.

Is the queue able to recover after a crash?

Comment: If your program crashes, any change is preserved.  If the last entry is incomplete it won't appear in the index.  To maximise performance it doesn't guarantee writes to disk so if your system crashes (e.g. a kernel panic) you can lose many GB of uncommitted changes (under heavy load)

Comment: You can make the batch sizes dynamic. i.e. read the waiting requests (up to some limit) process them, repeat.  This would result in small, responsive batches when load is relatively low and increasingly larger batches when under heavy load.